# What is the name of this part of banana under the peel (picture attached)

Tags: word-request

After peeling a banana almost always there are long and removable fibers(?) on the banana (marked by red arrows). What are they called?

[image]

Comment: In general, you need to let us know whether you want to know if there's a word *in common use* for this, or if you're after a technical term. It's not always clear from your questions.

Comment: I didn't assume that should be two terms (professional and colloquial) for that. But in retrospect I would like to know both.

Comment: A good addition is the word in your native language. If there is no word in your native language, you could explain why you expect their to be one in English

Comment: **1.** Maybe there is one in my native language. **2.** English is **richer** in vocabulary than the most of the languages and obviously my native language.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a word in your native language for this? If yes, what is it? I would have never considered that there was a name for this. And if I did, I would have probably used "fibers" as you have.

Comment: I don't know) It is not in the dictionary for banana. There is a translation for **phloem** only which you can find here for many languages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phloem

Comment: ["Mellow yellow"?](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/smoking-banana-peels-1960s-donovan-mellow-yellow-hoax)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From a [HuffPost article titled "FYI, Those Annoying **Strings** On Bananas Are Called **Phloem Bundles**"](https://m.huffpost.com/us/entry/us_59356f67e4b0c242ca25e7f8):

> We’re talking about those annoying white strings on bananas, or more technically, “phloem bundles.” (Appetizing name, right?)
>
> If the term “phloem” sounds familiar to you, it’s probably because you were taught about phloem and xylem when you learned about plant biology in middle school science class. Those two terms describe the complex tissues that transport food and water in a plant, providing it with sufficient food, nutrients, minerals and water to grow.
>
> So essentially, these hideous strings distribute nutrients up and down the banana as it grows, allowing us to eat the delicious bananas that we so love.

Therefore, in an informal conversation between friends, etc., I would expect to hear ***banana strings***. On the other hand, if you're writing an academic article or trying to come across as a know-all in an informal conversation, use the term ***phloem bundles***.

Comment: I call them _strings_, and I would **not** recommend calling them _phloem bundles_ in informal conversations – even when you _do_ want to appear as a know-it-all.

Comment: Interesting, even as a native speaker I never knew that. However I wonder if our language discriminates between the “thin” phloem strings (edible) and the “thick” ones (horrible and bitter)?